# Is abstract dual always geometric dual on specific condition?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Geometric dual is abstract dual for plane graphs.
G has abstract dual iff G is planar.
So abstract dual can be geometric dual or some other bijection.

But I guessed if G is planar and connected maybe abstract dual is always geometric dual. This might be true or false, but I have another question that if there is a condition that makes this proposition true. (eg. connectedness, 2-connectedness, etc...) Can you explain if there is?

Comment: Sorry, What is abstract dual and what is geometric dual?

Comment: Geometric dual:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricDualGraph.html
Abstract dual:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CombinatorialDualGraph.html
I'm sorry to not describe further... I'll do it when I have time

Answer (score 0):

“Whitney showed that the geometric dual graph and combinatorial dual graph are equivalent (Harary 1994, p. 115).” - [Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CombinatorialDualGraph.html)

Comment: But some Combi. Dual are not Geo. Dual, for example like some non-connected plane graphs. Only one geo. Dual for each graph but there can be 2+ combi. Dual for one graph.

Comment: Why do you think that? What’s different if between the two duals if there are multiple components?